# C++ CMD to simple Makefile with Clang and MingW

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, makefile, clang

I have successfully set Clang and MingW on Windows so I can run this following command:

```
clang++ -target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu helloworld.cpp -o helloworld.exe -v
```

Question:
**How to convert that simple cmd into Makefile compliant?**

I'm totally new to this.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Makefile

helloworld.exe: helloworld.cpp
    clang++ -v -target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu -o $@ $^
```

References:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables
- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Example